# Support vertex in a graph.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, terminology

I was going through some article and it mentioned "***support vertex***" of a graph. Is support vertex defined for any graph or only for trees. Kindly help. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A support vertex is defined as a vertex adjacent to a leaf and a leaf is a vertex of degree $1$ in a tree so yes, it is only for trees.